# JPanel is just white/grey

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

EDIT2: I also get a white/grey area, if I try to add a JLabel to the area, where the checkboxes are, that you see in the second image.

EDIT: **Also note this:** When I just create a JLabel and add it before totalResultArea is added to panelResults, it also only shows a white/grey area.

I created two JPanels `panelResults` and `totalResultArea`, **but only see a white/grey area for the second panel (`totalResultArea`).**

At first I set the layout of `panelResults` to `GridBagLayout`

```
JPanel panelResults = new JPanel();
JPanel totalResultArea = new JPanel();
panelResults.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Then I add the `totalResultArea` to `panelResults`:

```
GridBagContraints  c = new GridBagConstraints();
totalResultArea.setLayout(new BoxLayout(totalResultArea, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridwidth = 2;
c.weightx = 2;
panelResults.add(totalResultArea, c);
```

In a click-event-listener of a button I add a `JLabel` to the `totalResultArea` and set the `JFrame` visible:

```
JLabel totalResultsText = new JLabel("<html><body>...</body></html>");
totalResultArea.add(totalResultsText);

// revalidate and repaint totalResultArea and panelResults
totalResultArea.revalidate();
totalResultArea.repaint();
panelResults.revalidate();
panelResults.repaint();

// add panelResults to frame
frame.getContentPane().add(panelResults, BorderLayout.NORTH);

// invalidate, repaint the frame and make it visible 
frame.invalidate();
frame.repaint();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This all looks like this:

[image: white/grey JPanel]

[image]

I hope you can reproduce this. If not see the picture.

**What could be the reson, that I don't see the text from the JLabel, but an only white/grey area?**

Comment: You added `JLabel` after you passed `totalResultArea` to `panelResults`?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski yes, but I also set `frame.setVisible(true)` and I also `ìnvalidate()` and `repaint()` the `JPanel`. Also I did the same with another `JPanel` (I added the radio buttons and checkboxes after adding the `JPanel` for this and that worked).

Comment: Which `JPanel` did you repaint()? You need to repaint whole hierarchy.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I do `frame.invalidate();
frame.repaint();`

Comment: You need to repaint `totalResultsArea` and `panelResults` frames also

Comment: try `revalidate` instead of `invalidate`

Comment: I used 'new JLabel("<html><body><h1>HEADER</h1></body></html>");' and it worked fine

Comment: @RafałLaskowski, @MatheM That doesn't work either (tried both at once). Also note **this:** When I just create a JLabel and add it before `totalResultsArea` is added to `panelResults`, it also only shows a white/grey area.

Comment: Did you add `panelResults` to `frame`?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski yes, I did in the button-event-handler-method.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux Edit your question with code where you add `panelResults` to `frame` for someone else. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Found another `invalidate()` in another class, that invalidated the `frame.getContentPane()` which could have been it. However can't test it today anymore.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux Let us know tomorrow then :)

Comment: `I hope you can reproduce this.` no, because you didn't post a proper [mcve]. We can't guess  the context of how the code you posted is used. `set the main-JFrame visible:` - don't know what that means. An application should only have a single JFrame, so it should already be visible. If you are dynamically creating a new window it should be a JDialog and there would be no need for revalidate() or anything as you just need to add the components to the dialog and make it visible.

Comment: @camickr I only have one JFrame (besides I can imagine applications with multiple windows). Sorry for being unclear. My code is far too extensiv and it was hard to select. So I could not just post all of it. I think calling `frame.setVisible(true);` is important.

Comment: `My code is far too extensiv` - and the point of the [mcve] is to simplify the code to demonstrate the problem. Chances are while you do this you will find your problem.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski @MatheM it still does not work :-/ There was another JPanel, that did not work until I made this change, but the one I asked this question for still does not work. I made sure there are no `.invalidate()` in the project anymore, also there are no `.validate()` - only `.revalidate()`.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski This is strange, I also get a white/grey area, if I try to add a JLabel to the area, where the checkboxes are, that you [see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWM8f.png), is this maybe a caching problem or something? How can I clean project in IntelliJ?

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux How many JFrames do you use?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski just a single one. But I replace the items at some time.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux What was the logic behind making `frame.setVisible(true)` inside `click-event-listener`?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I thought, that I read somewhere that it is necessary. Maybe it's not. I also do `frame.setVisible(true)` at the very end of the main-function.

Comment: Is it possible that there is just something wrong with the colors? It looks like the background- and the foreground-color are both white. Try to output the current used colors or change it to something else.

Comment: You say that you replace items (components) in your panels. Make sure that you remove the old components (the ones being replaced) before you add the new ones. Some layout managers do this for you but you shouldn't rely on that. Your code example has a typo. The names of panels are TotalResultArea and TotalResult**s**Area are you sure you are adding correct panel or is this a typo?

Comment: @MatheM I use `.removeAll()` to remove all previous items first. I corrected the typo. I only have one totalResultArea, so that wasn't an issue, but thanks anyways. I moved the project to windows and there everything works. I can add JLabel under Windows and I can add JPanel and it is all display. I tried moving the very same project back from Windows to linux (arch linux), but it does not work there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background- and the font-color of the label are both white so you can't see the text.

When you take paint and fill the label with another color you will see that there is a text.

[image: Image to see that there is text]

So check your style and/or add `totalResultsText.setForeground(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: I guess you use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` so there must be something wrong with the LookAndFeel provided by the OS.

Comment: Also the white background usually doesn't come from the `JLabel` since it doesn't have any so it must be the parent Pane which has a white background.

Comment: you seem to be right! I added `totalResultsText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);` and it shows the text! However apart from that I only set the fore- and background-color of the `radioOrCheckbox` (`radioOrCheckbox.setBackground(backgroundColor); radioOrCheckbox.setForeground(foregroundColor);`). **I don't see, why the JLabel gets dispayed white instead of black** (like one can see on the pictures). Yes, I use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` so the white font should be alright (white on black). How can the JLabel be white on white?